# TypeError: 'StreamReader' object is not subscriptable while slicing the headers from file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am facing this error when running the below code

```
from io import StringIO
class Runner(object):
  @staticmethod
  def runner(file_object):
    data = file_object.readlines()
    
    bdy = data[2:]
    
    for line in bdy:
      yield line
```

Error Log:

```
bdy = data[2:]
TypeError: 'StreamReader' object is not subscriptable
```

The error seems to be in bdy where it is not able to slice the data list that is obtained from file_object.readlines

Need to Fix this.

Comment: Please `print(len(data))` and tell us what you get.

Comment: TypeError: object of type 'StreamReader' has no len() <- Getting this error

Comment: So please spend the time to explain **by code** what `file_object` is, and how you initialize it.

Comment: The Type of the data is StreamReader. once I did file_object.readlines(), it returned a StreamReader

Comment: And you do understand that a `StreamReader` is **not** an array which you can use `[2:]` on, right?

Comment: Yeah I got that now as I checked. I was under the assumption that it is a list that is returned. Can you tell me how to read the list from this StreamReader?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to istanciate the class object in another part of the code and in that part you are calling the method runner but before make sure you opened the file correctly in read mode.

```
file = open("*your filename*", "r")
```

Finally you can call the method

```
my_runner = Runner()
my_runner.runner(file)
```

also it's good practice to close the file too

```
file.close()
```

If the problem persists check the length of the file, its existance in the folder and its path.